# Let an app sign documents, but don't let it see the keys

Tags: linux, security, digital-signature, private-key

I want to digitally sign documents and messages on a Linux server. How do I securely store the private key and a passphrase if any?

The problem is, if an application gets compromised, keys would also become compromised. If I could [somehow let an app sign something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672005/where-to-store-the-private-key-on-a-digital-signing-server?rq=1), but don't let it touch actual keys, that wouldn't completely solve my problem (as an attacker would still be able to sign anything for some time), but reduce the impact (like, we won't have to revoke the keys).

For example, in case of SSL servers there's no such problem because usually there's no practical need for an application to access the keys. Hence, they can be semi-securely stored in a separate location. E.g. a webserver (like nginx) would be able to read the keys, but not the application.

Am I overthinking it? Is it even worthy thinking of?

Comment: If you find that an application has been compromised, why would you assume that no other applications, or files, were similarly compromised? Surely, in the event of a machine being compromised, it would be sensible to revoke and reissue the keys regardless, if only to be absolutely sure? Incidentally, this question may be worth posting on [Security.se], but check their [help pages](http://security.stackexchange.com/help) first.

Comment: @DavidThomas That's my question too. Should I worry about this at all?

Comment: I honestly don't know; I'm pretty sure that a once-compromised system should not be trusted (until a full wipe, and reinstall, has taken place), but as to the security-related questions, I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a separate, lightweight signing application that listens on an UNIX socket and runs as a separate user from the main app; when your app wants to sign something it throws the file and any additional info down that socket, and gets back the signed file.

If the application ever gets compromised the attacker will still be able to sign files as long as he is still on the server, but unless he uses a privilege escalation exploit to get root privileges and copy the signing app's key, he won't he able to steal the key and then sign at will without being connected to the server.

You can replace the UNIX socket with a standard TCP socket and put the signing app on a separate server for extra security; make sure to implement some basic access control on the signing app and of course use proper firewall rules to make sure the signing server is never exposed to the internet, or simplify things a bit by [using a "setuid" binary for signing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5676729/2629998) that gets invoked by your app, in that case the signing binary will run as a different user with additional privileges to access the keys, while the webapp itself doesn't have such privileges.

Basically you should implement a rudimentary software HSM.

Answer (score 1):

If you have very high security needs you could consider moving the keys to a completely independent server, or better yet a hardware security module (but those are expensive). Like you mention it can help prevent the loss of keys, but if the app is compromised the attacker could still sign whatever they wanted.

The main reason to go through the trouble then is auditing. That is if you have your signing server or device keep logs of everything it signs, then if only your app is compromised you will be better able to assess the extent of the damage (assuming you're signing server has not been compromised).

So yes there are benefits, but your first focus should be on securing your main application properly, because once that's compromised you're already having a very bad no good day, even if you have moved your keys to a sperate service.